# How can we trigger X when the user says y ANYWHERE

Tags: c#, user-input

For example

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input your age: ");
string age = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please input your first name: ");
string firstname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please input your last name: ");
string lastname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Thank you!");
```

Now pretend I have something like this but with a lot of more questions. Then I wouldn't want to keep putting an `if` statement on each one. How would I make it run this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("beta")
```

whenever the user says "alpha" without putting `if` statements on each user input?

Comment: Your example is not very explanatory :) You're not taking any user input or doing anything with that input. Why don't you show real code?

Comment: There is no real code, im just wondering how would i do that.

Comment: You could create a function encapsulating the input prompt and the logic to process the input.. in any case it's very hard to give you an accurate answer with the amount of information you provided.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi i put code in the post, is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, make a function that receives a prompt and returns the response.  Inside that, you can check for "alpha" and output "beta", though I suspect that's not ~really~ what you need to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string age = GetResponse("Please input your age: ");
    string firstname = GetResponse("Please input your first name: ");
    string lastname = GetResponse("Please input your last name: ");
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you!");
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string GetResponse(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string response = Console.ReadLine();
    if (response == "alpha")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("beta");
    }
    return response;
}
```